# rabbitmq flow control logging

Tags: rabbitmq, flow-control

We have low-latency application (messages need to be processed in less than 200ms). There are periods of time when messages are not delivered for a few seconds. I would like to detect if there was rabbitmq flow control mechanism applied in this period (e.g. because of queue mirroring). Is there any possibility to view (or to log) flow control history?
Thanks a lot.